# Detect android system date/time format change and reflect in the app

Tags: java, android

I want the app to correspond to the system time format change. For Instance, if i change android system time format to 24hr format. I want my app to detect that change and reflect the change in the app. Hence if the system time format is 24hrs then the time displayed inside the app should be in 24hrs as well and vice versa if is 12hrs format.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the system time format by using this code:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
String pattern = dateFormat.toLocalizedPattern(); //if you want the string pattern
```

There is no way to listen for a time format change action, but giving that this action is always made outside your application, you can put the code in your Activity's / Fragment's `onResume()` method and change the UI accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `BroadcastReceiver` with intent filter "*android.intent.action.TIME_SET*" for detect 12/24 time format change. It may be delayed by 10-30 seconds.

```
    <receiver android:name=".BroadcastReceiverMy" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```